# Gatling.io отправка события socket.io

Tags: websocket, socket.io, scala, gatling

Осваиваю новый для себя инструмент Gatling.io и столкнулся с проблемой синтаксиса отправки события socket.io. Вот мой код

```
import BasicLoad.start
import Requests.usersLogin
import io.gatling.core.ConfigKeys.socket
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.scenario.Simulation
import io.gatling.jsonpath
import io.socket.client.{IO, Socket}
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter.Listener
import org.json.JSONObject

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

class ServerLoad extends Simulation{

  val port = Integer.getInteger("port", 8080)
  val host = System.getProperty("host", "localhost")
  val wsUrl = "wss://$host:$port/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=" + "${sessionId}"
  val socketUrl = "https://localhost:8080"
  val optConnect = new IO.Options()

  val users = csv("./users.csv")
    .circular
  val httpConf = http.baseUrl("https://localhost")
    /*.userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " +
      "Chrome/81.0.4044.138 YaBrowser/20.4.3.268 (beta) Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36")*/
    .wsBaseUrl("wss://localhost:8080")
  val scn = scenario("UsersLogin").feed(users).during(10 second){
      //exec(usersLogin)
     exec(ws("Connect").connect("/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket").headers(
       Map(
         "User-Agent" -> "${device}"
       )
     )
     )
     .pause(1)
     .exec(session => {
       optConnect.forceNew = false
       optConnect.timeout = 10000
       val obj = new JSONObject()
       obj.put("login", "${login}")
       obj.put("password", "${password}")
       obj.put("APILevel", "${level}")
       val socket = IO.socket( socketUrl, optConnect )
       socket.connect()
       socket.on( Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Listener {
         override def call(args: Any*): Unit = { //Здесь ошибка
           socket.emit("login", obj)
         }
        }
       )
      }
     )
     .exec(ws("Close connect").close)
    }

  setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(1)  during(5 second)).
    protocols(httpConf))
    .maxDuration(15 second)
}
```

При сборке IDE ругается

```
/home/pbezpal/roschat/testing-roschat/load-testing/Gatling/src/test/scala/ServerLoad.scala:49:17
type mismatch;
 found   : io.socket.emitter.Emitter
 required: io.gatling.commons.validation.Validation[io.gatling.core.session.Session]
       socket.on( Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Listener {
```

Как правильно написать код, чтобы отправить событие на сервер?

Comment: в тэги бы "scala", как минимум

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

С этим разобрался

```
.exec(session => {
       val obj = new JSONObject()
       val aknowledge = null
       obj.put("login", "${login}")
       obj.put("password", "${password}")
       obj.put("APILevel", "${level}")
       optConnect.forceNew = false
       optConnect.timeout = 10000
       val socket = IO.socket( socketUrl, optConnect )
       val printListener: Emitter.Listener = new Emitter.Listener {
         override def call(args: AnyRef*): Unit = {
         }
       }
       socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, printListener)
       socket.connect()
       socket.emit("login",obj)
       session
      }
     )
```

Теперь вопрос, как передать сюда значение из файла ./users.csv? Сейчас у меня отправляется не значение из файла, а ${login}

Comment: Ответили здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63503498/gatling-io-scala-socket-io